# How can we control size of the arrowhead in Graphics3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to change the size of the head in a specific way such that the distance from the top to the base of the head becomes smaller.

```
Graphics3D[{Orange, Arrowheads[0.1], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.03]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

I would like the head to shrink only in one direction and be like this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw a cone as the new arrow.

```
arrow = Graphics3D[{Cone[{{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, .5]}];
Graphics3D[{Orange, Arrowheads[{{0.1, 1, {arrow, 1}}}], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.03]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]